# Ajax Post request returns internal error 500?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am making a project for local use using jQuery and Node.js + Express API.
When I "place an order" using Postman there is no problem:

[image]

When I do, what seems to me, the same with jQuery, I get an internal server error 500:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:3001/roomorder",
        data: {
            roomOrderLines: global_orderSummary,
        },
        dataType: "json",

        success: (placeOrderResult) => {

            $('#appContent').html(`success!`);
        },

        error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) => {
            global_setError("An error occurred. / "+xhr.status+" / "+thrownError);
        }
    });
```

the global_orderSummary looks like this when I console.log it, looks identical to me as what I use as data in Postman:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check your node server console, that should give more clues. Perhaps the ajax post doesn't post what you think it does

Comment: my node server console is not throwing any errors

Comment: You wrote that it returns 500, so it must be on the express side of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make these adjustments, now it works:

```
type: "post",
url: "http://localhost:3001/roomorder",
data: JSON.stringify ({roomOrderLines: global_orderSummary}),
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
```